Problem with installing react.js on ubuntu 22.04: dpkg: error processing archive
I am trying to install react.js on ubuntu 22.04. I am following the website:
https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-reactjs-on-ubuntu-22-04/
When I am executing the command:
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

I am getting following error:

dpkg: error processing archive
/var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_18.20.3-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
(--unpack):  trying to overwrite '/usr/include/node/common.gypi',
which is also in package libnode-dev 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3.5 dpkg-deb:
error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe) Errors were
encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_18.20.3-1nodesource1_amd64.deb E:
Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I have tried:
cd /var/cache/apt/archives
 $ sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite 'nodejspackage.db'

but I am getting the error:

dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'nodejspackage.db': No such file or
directory

Somebody please guide me.
Zulfi.
